# want to Set Value random index to item and corresponding image to tempImages in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to get label so that it can be set to **ptags** to display inside class **box** and push currusponding item to **tempImages[]**
like i have already done.

The code shown **Const randItem2** which selects random label and its url without duplicates from array **Items**

In short, how to display the randomly selected value without duplicates  **Const randItem2**  its label value to **ptags** and its url to its **tempImages[]** , like the same effects as code below Const randItem2

Is there any way i can achieve this?

```js
var tempimages = [];

function rvalue() {
  const
    items = [  
      { label: '1', url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=1'  },
      { label: '2', url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=2'  },
      { label: '3', url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=3'  },
      { label: '4', url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=4'  },
      { label: '5', url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=5'  },
      { label: '6', url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=6'  },
      { label: '7', url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=7'  },
      { label: '8', url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=8'  },
      { label: '9', url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=9'  },
      { label: '10',url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=10' }
          ],
ptags = document.querySelectorAll('[name="values"]');
  
  
 
var lastnumber=0;  
for (let index = 0; index < 3; index++) 
  {
      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length),
     // const randItem2 = Array.from({ length: 3 },() => {const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);const [item] =                                                        items.splice(randomIndex, 1);return item;

      item = items[randomIndex];
      ptags[index].textContent = item.label;
      tempimages.push(item);
 
     
  }

}


function displayAllImages() {

  if (tempimages.length === 0) 
  {
    return;
  }
  
   
    item = tempimages.shift(),

    image = document.getElementById('slide');
 
  image.src = item.url;
};

$(function() {
 
  rvalue();
  displayAllImages(); 
}); 

function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();

  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  var el = document.getElementById(data);

  el.parentNode.removeChild; 
 
  ev.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = 'initial'; 

  var pParagraph = ev.currentTarget.firstElementChild;
  ev.currentTarget.removeChild(pParagraph);
  
  // Show the next image in the slider..
  displayAllImages();
}
```

```css
#container {
  margin-top:-2%;
  white-space:nowrap;
  text-align:center;
  margin-left:20%;
  margin-right:30%;
}

.box {
  background-color: coral;
  width: 60px;
  height:60px;
  margin-top:10px;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:5px;
  border:2px solid #333;
  border-color: #e6e600;
  border-radius: 10%;
  background-color:  #ff00ff;
}

.box002 {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin-left:30%;
  margin-top:-20px;
  padding-top:2%;
  background-color:#ffff00 2px;
  border:2px solid #000066;
} 

.text {
  padding: 20px;
  margin:7 px;
  margin-top:10px;
  color:white;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align:center;
}

#container {
  white-space:nowrap;
  text-align:center;
  margin-left:20%;
  margin-right:30%;
}

.text {
  padding: 20px;
  margin:7 px;
  margin-top:10px;
  color:white;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onload="rvalue()">

<div class="containerr">
    
<div id="container" style="margin-bottom:10%">

<div class="box"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="10"><p name="values"></p></div>

<div class="box"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="11"><p name="values"></p></div>

<div class="box"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="12"><p name="values"></p></div>

            </div>
</div>



    
<div class="box002" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="2">

         <img src=""  draggable="true" id="slide" style="width:30px; height:30px; border-radius: 50%;" border="rounded"/>
        
</div> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid duplicates you have to keep generating the next random number till it is unique.

Either you can use tempimages variable, which contains an item & every item contains a label...or you can create a separate variable to maintain list of used numbers.

Comment: The code i have , // const randItem2 = Array.from({ length: 3 },() => {const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);const [item] =                                                        items.splice(randomIndex, 1);return item;      remove duplicates but dont know how to set item, ptags , temp images from it.

Comment: is there a way to do it?

Comment: ptags is used for displaying number on class box,   tempImages for displaying corresponding number image(used placeholder) to display in class .box002